# Verb describing an action of a vehicle turning its wheels but not moving anywhere

Tags: word-request

What's the right verb in English to describe an action of a vehicle turning its wheels but not moving anywhere due to muddy or icy road?

For example:

> We drove Jack's car over the woods having not paid due attention to
>   the fact that it had rained the night before. The path was rather
>   muddy and, soon enough, our car _________________.

(a past-tense verb or verb phrase in the blank)

Comment: "our car **was spinning its wheels**."

Comment: *our car got stuck in the mud*.

Comment: @Anatolii - But does "got stuck" imply that wheels are still turning?

Comment: @user105719 - Thank you. This is the answer. You can re-write it as an answer and I will accept it then.

Comment: @brilliant no, it doesn't. The answer from user105719 is the correct one.

Comment: You're welcome. I know I'm a bad cyber-citizen for answering in a comment, but an answer would require checking a dictionary of slang phrases to find out the history of the phrase, noting its metaphorical usage, and quoting a good example from an English corpora. I'm not up to the effort today.

Comment: @user105719 - I fully understand and agree with you.